Does this P-Trap look correct? (Metal nut on PVC)
My contractor had his plumber come and install this P-Trap on my disposal. I feel like I've read that you shouldn't put metal nuts on PVC threads, but I'm not sure if that's true in all cases. Does this look right? It's not leaking.
Edit: It's painted plastic.


It is not metal, just painted plastic, use magnet to confirm

By golly, you're right! Thanks.

I’m voting to close this question because the original premise was faulty.

The trap looks a little dodgy, just a little.
When they glue the pipes they're supposed to use a primer with the glue and this will usually make red or purple stains. (unless they're using the clear primer that's intended for making patio furniture.)
The parts seem to be mismatched, but they fit together alright which is the main thing.  I get the impression that this trap was made from left-over parts that they had on hand, but apart from the invisible primer I can't fault it.
More worrying is that electrical cable, that's not even close to being allowed. it's way too close to that wire mesh patch, that splice should be in a box, and that is the wrong cable to use outside of the wall. and the wrong way to run wire out of a wall.
